# Wordpress Logo .oam (edge animate)

Tags: wordpress, animation

i build my logo effect with "Adobe Edge animate" and export it us logo.oam
How can i make it my logo in Wordpress website?

i already try to upload it to image upload but wordpress don't let you do that.`logoeffe.oam This file type is not allowed. Please try another.`
thanks for reply

Comment: Well, the error message says it all. Please read up on what adobe Edge animate generates (HTML5 animations), and try to understand why that cannot work with an image uploads (not an image).

Answer (score 0):

here is the wordpress media supported file type.
https://en.support.wordpress.com/accepted-filetypes/

You can check this. If you want to extend the file type then add this code in functions.php file-

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'oam_upload_mimes');
function oam_upload_mimes ( $mimes=array() ) {
    $mimes['oam'] = 'application/postscript';
return $mimes;
}
```

Then wordpress media give you permission to upload oam file in media.